# How to run JavaScript code before document is fully loaded with QWebEngineView?

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I would like to evaluate JavaScript before page's document is constructed and its scripts evaluated, in essence emulating [Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument) of Chrome Devtools Protocol.

I tried to evaluate the JS code on [loadStarted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#loadStarted) and [loadProgress](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#loadProgress) events of `QWebEngineView` but the script was evaluated only after page fully loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QWebEngineScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginescript.html) to do this. It allows you to set an [injection point](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginescript.html#InjectionPoint-enum) and [execution world](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginescript.html#ScriptWorldId-enum) for your script (similar to e.g. greasemonkey).